# Classifying groups of order 18

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to classify groups of order 18. So far, I have shown that a group $G$ of order 18 is given by $G\cong C_9 \rtimes_{\varphi} C_2$ or $G\cong (C_3 \times C_3)\rtimes_{\varphi} C_2$.

If $G\cong C_9 \rtimes_{\varphi} C_2$, then $\mid \varphi(1) \mid$ divides $2$, so that $\varphi(1)$ is trivial or inverts a generator of $C_9$. I concluded that $G \cong C_{18}$ in the former case and $G \cong D_{18}$ in the latter case.

I am now considering the case $G\cong (C_3 \times C_3)\rtimes_{\varphi} C_2$, but I am stuck. I have found [this article](http://www.math.utk.edu/~finotti/f06/g18.pdf), but they do not do it the same way as me (finding the image of $\varphi(1)$ in $Aut(C_3 \times C_3)$).

Is there a way to do this using my method? My goal is to be able to do questions like this on my algebra qual without having to fiddle around. I was messing around with the fact that $Aut(C_3 \times C_3)\cong GL_2(C_3)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\varphi(1)$ is an automorphism of $C_3 \times C_3$ of order $1$ or $2$. If it has order $1$, then you get the direct product $C_3 \times C_3 \times C_2 \cong C_3 \times C_6$, so let's suppose it has order $2$.

It helps to think of ${\rm Aut}(C_3 \times C_3)$ as the group ${\rm GL}(2,3)$ of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices over the field of order $3$. An element of order $2$ has minimal polynomial $x^2-1$  or $x+1$       , so it has eigenvalues $1,-1$ or $-1,-1$. In either case, the matrix is diagonalizable.

So, we can find generators $t,u$ of  $C_3 \times C_3$ (corresponding to eigenvectors of the matrix) such that, in the first case, $\phi(1)$maps $t \mapsto t$, $u \mapsto u^{-1}$ and, in the second case $t \mapsto t^{-1}$, $u \mapsto u^{-1}$. So there are two isomorphism classes of nontrivial semidirect products.

Comment: @CensiLI: In one case the involution fixes an element of $C_3^2$, in the other case not. So once the center of $G$ is $C_3$ and once trivial.

Comment: @CensiLI For exercises of this type, I prefer to give outline arguments  rather than completely detailed  solutions.

Comment: Minimal polynomial could be $x+1$ or $x-1$

Comment: It can't be $x-1$ because the element has order 2.

Comment: How do you know the order $2$ matrix is diagonalizable in the case when eigenvalues are $-1, -1$?

Comment: That's an easy exercise. But more generally, any matrix of finite order in which all eigenvalues lie in the field is diagonalizable.

Comment: @DerekHolt Even if the eigenvalues are not distinct? Could you point me to proof? Thanks though!

Comment: The minimal polynomial divides $x^n-1$ for some $n$, which has distinct roots. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685104) for example.

Comment: @DerekHolt how do you know that an element of order 2 corresponds to $t \to t$ and $ u \to u^{-1}$?

Comment: That's just basic linear algebra. A $2 \times 2$ matrix over a field $K$ represents a linear map $K^2 \to K^2$, and we are identifying $C_3 \times C_3$ with $K^2$, where $K$ is the field of order $3$.